# Php excel create excel for multidimensional array

Tags: php, php-5.6

I am getting array like this in a variable now i want to create an excel using this in this format how can i loop through this to get
 excel in that way. format of excel on which way i want to disply my
 data on excel please help me related this i am newbe here thanx in
 advance

```
Array
(
            [id] => 266
            [comp] => 374
            [freq] => Week 1
            [empComp] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                    [name] => ABC
                    [value] => 123
                    [age] => 19
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => XYZ
                            [value] => 123
                            [age] => 20
                       ) 

        )

)


Array
(
            [id] => 277
            [comp] => 355
            [freq] => Week 2
            [empComp] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                    [name] => ABC1
                    [value] => 1231
                    [age] => 21
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => XYZ1
                            [value] => 1231
                            [age] => 22
                       ) 

        )

)



....................................................
id      |     226       |      comp     |    374 |             
....................................................
name    |      value          |     age            |
....................................................
ABC     |     123             |          19        |
XYZ     |     423             |          20        |
....................................................
id      |     277       |      comp     |    355 |             
....................................................
name    |      value          |     age            |
....................................................
ABC1     |     1231             |          21       |
XYZ1    |     4231             |          22        |
.....................................................
```

Comment: i have tried but i ve not found any solution for array inside array fields thats y iam asking this

Comment: Please go read [ask]. _Show us_ what you tried (even if it was not successful - it at least shows _that_ you tried something, and are not just pretending you did), and explain what _exactly_ your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your array is stored in the `$mainArr`.

You can write something like this to achieve your desired output.

I'm displaying result in the table format, but you can place your excel syntax.

```
echo "<table>";

foreach($mainArr as $values){

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . "id" . "</td><td>" . $values['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" ."comp " . "</td><td>" . $values['comp'] ." </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Name</td>";
    echo "<td>Value</td>";
    echo "<td>Age</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    foreach($values['empComp'] as $value){ 

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $value['name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $value['value'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $value['age'] ."</td>";
    }
}

echo "</table>";
```

Let me know if above code is giving you required output.